# Calculating with javascript

Tags: javascript

ok so i have this html and i want to calculate quantity * pricePerItem with the numbers i put in the input .
Thx in advance.

## Book store

```
<h3>Please select your books</h3>
<div>
    <label for="quantity">Quantity</label>
    <input type="text" id="quantity" />
</div>
<div>
    <label for="quantity">Price per item</label>
    <input type="text" id="pricePerItem" />
</div>
<div>
    <button>View price</button>
</div>
<div class="payment-info">
    Amount to pay: <span id="total"></span>
</div>


$(document).ready(function() {
var quantity = $("#quantity");
var price = $("#pricePerItem");

$("total").text(price * quantity);
});`
```

Comment: can someone tell me what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

$('button').on('click',function(){
  var quantity = parseFloat($("#quantity").val());
var price = parseFloat($("#pricePerItem").val());
$('#total').html(price * quantity);
});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Please select your books</h3>
<div>
    <label for="quantity">Quantity</label>
    <input type="text" id="quantity" />
</div>
<div>
    <label for="quantity">Price per item</label>
    <input type="text" id="pricePerItem" />
</div>
<div>
    <button>View price</button>
</div>
<div class="payment-info">
    Amount to pay: <span id="total"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that with

```
var quantity = $("#quantity");
```

you are just selecting the html input element in the variable quantity and not getting the value of the input element.

Also, you also have to add a `event listener`on the button to get the value everytime you make any changes to the value in the input element.

Please find the attached code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        var quantity = $('#quantity').val()
        var price = $('#pricePerItem').val()
        var total = quantity*price;        
        $('#total').text(total);    
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

### HTML

```
    <h3>Please select your books</h3>
    <div>
      <label for="quantity">Quantity</label>
      <input type="text" id="quantity" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="quantity">Price per item</label>
      <input type="text" id="pricePerItem" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <button onclick="calculateTotal();">View price</button>
    </div>
    <div class="payment-info">Amount to pay: <span id="total"></span>
    </div>
```

### JS

```
   function calculateTotal() {
        var quantity = $("#quantity").text();
        var price = $("#pricePerItem").text();

        $("#total").text(quantity * price);
    }
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/pctAxRZ80Zr8Q8e0zm2g?p=info